# Washer and Dryer on one 20amp breaker?

Tags: electrical

We just moved into a home built in 1998. The previous owners had a standard washing machine and looks like were using an electric dryer.

We have chosen to go with a gas dryer instead. There was a gas line there already so it made for an easy connection. My question is on the electrical part.

Right now the washer is on a 20amp circuit with terminates with a single 20amp outlet. The new washer states it needs 10amps.  The dryer states it needs 13 amps. Can I turn the single outlet into a double 20amp outlet? Is it okay to have both the dryer and washer on the same outlet/breaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely install a duplex outlet in the place of the 20 amp outlet.  As for it not tripping a breaker; you can try and see.  It should not be dangerous if wired properly with a functioning breaker and #12 wire with properly tightened connections.

If the breaker trips, you know you need to get some additional copper to the laundry area.  It probably will not trip though.

Answer (score 1):

The poblem(s) with your scenario is one 20 amp breaker it's only good for 20 amps under normal usage.  Your washer and dryer combined equals 23 amps. Granted you may not run both at the same time but who's to say the next homeowner will not.

Comment: A) A 20A circuit is good for 20A, not 18. B) NEC code does not at all say a washer needs to be dedicated, nor a gas dryer. ........ Neither a washer or gas dryer are considered a continuous load.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I just assumed because the laundry room requires a dedicated circuit.  But now I know.  The 18 amps is just a rule of thumb I thought everyone practiced not to max out the circuit.